# Java SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, ssl

Все привет!

Написал https сервер с сертификатом и ключами.
При подключении к нему джава клиента, происходит корректное подключение по ssl.

Но вот при попытке подключиться через firefox, я наблюдаю ошибку на сервере: SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common.

Я скачал с оф сайта JCE пакеты для джавы.И решил проверить какие cipher suits доступны, вызвав `SSLServerSocketFactory#SSLServerSocketFactory`
Потом определил cipher suits браузера. И оказалось, что между ними действительно нет общего сьюта.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848047/how-to-add-unsupported-cipher-suitesnot-included-in-the-default-cipher-suites здесь смотрели?

Comment: @Zergatul да, не помогает. Что меня вводит в заблуждение, это cipher suits у меня совсем другой чем у firefox. Я вручную проверил - ни одного общего сьюта.

Comment: ну тогда остается подключать какой-то Bouncy Castle, там легко можно добавлять cipher cuite'ы (я в c# делал).

Comment: @Zergatul 5 секунд назад тоже об этом подумал) спасибо.

Comment: @Zergatul правильно я понимаю, что bouncy castel предоставляют свои алгоритмы шифрования, которые можно использовать в жаве?

Comment: да, у них там своя имплементация всех алгоритмов

Comment: @Zergatul Я установил bouncy castle provider, но ошибка повторяется. Нужно ли его явно установить в HttpsServer ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74295/discussion-between-voipp-and-zergatul).